# I have install wine 1.6.2 and 1.7 both not working in my system?

Tags: 14.04, wine

I have install successfully wine 1.6.2 when i try to install youtube downloader then error comes- path not found. Same goes for wine 1.7. What should i do?

Comment: There are plenty of browser addons and linux native programs to download youtube videos.

Answer (score 1):

Just use youtube-dl. You will realized it's the only reliable one that can download youtube videos on linux. I have tried miro and it wasn't very good. So I go bare bones and use youtube-dl.

### Install it

```
sudo pip install youtube-dl
```

### Downloading a video is easy

1. `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k85mRPqvMbE`

or

2. `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k85mRPqvMbE -o crazyFrog.mp4`

Youtube-dl is pretty powerful tool even though it doesn't have a UI.

### Sometimes thing might not work well, so update

```
sudo youtube-dl --update
```

Answer (score 0):

Or why not use online software without installing anything on your computer try this: http://ytconv.net/

This website will give you a hyperlink once the video is available for download and even converts it to your preferred format. If you really want physically installed software try going to the software center and install playonlinux. please post your results.

Comment: no any other software install in system from wine. always error come "path not found"